# Told I'll get a 5% wage drop, but I never got a raise when I became supervisor

Tags: salary, employment, ireland

I have been supervisor for 7 years and wish to move back down. I have been told I will get a 5% wage drop if I move down. When I moved up to supervisor I was not given a raise for the new position.

I have had a couple of % raises each year, as is standard in my company, since taking the supervisor position. I would have received the same if I had stayed in my lower position.

My wage is already lower than some staff who are not supervisors. I have worked as supervisor for 7 years on an insulting wage.

I accepted the supervisor position with no increase as times were very bad back then.

I have never signed a contract for the supervisor position. 
There is no union.

I am working in Ireland. There is high unemployment in my area so I can't walk into another position.

I feel intimidated by my manager and I am scared I will be bullied more or let go if I stand up for myself.

What should I do? Stay in the supervisor role or drop down and refuse the pay drop based on the fact I didn't get a raise.

To make this more appropriate...

What are my rights and my employers rights in this situation? Am I not legally entitled to refuse the drop based on no contracted wage increase for the supervisor position?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Don't move back down and immediately start looking for another job.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know what to do. Stay in the supervisor role or drop down and refuse the pay drop based on the fact I didn't get a raise.

Comment: How far in the "moving down" process are you?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other company I can move to in the area. I own a house with a mortgage here.

Comment: There is little we can tell you. You seem to have all your options on the table. Making the final decision is up to you.

Comment: @magnum In the process of moving down, I have said I want to and have been told by my manager that head office have told my manager I would get a 5% drop. I have not signed anything.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the pay cut is not something you have control over, even if you don't sign anything. You'll have to check your contract and consult a lawyer, but as far as I know, in most countries the only options you have are to accept the pay cut and keep working there, or not to accept the pay cut and losing your job.

Comment: @nvoigt is there anything with the fact I didn't sign a contract for the supervisor position? I never got a wage as part of the step up. Can they force me to take the wage drop? It's about 3-400 a month drop.

Comment: Politely question the reasoning for this while pointing out that you didn't get a raise when moving to a supervisor position. If that doesn't do anything, just make your decision - we can't do it for you.

Comment: @MByrne You have established that you are totally dependent on them. No other jobs you can take, no unions, no current contract, you wil be fired if you stand up for yourself... this is slavery. If this is true, you have to take what you get.

Comment: @MByrne http://www.workplacerelations.ie/en/ has a wealth of information about your rights as an employee in Ireland. And be honest with yourself, Ireland is small enough that you can get a job anywhere if you're qualified enough and can drive (unless you're living up further north). I reckon if you ask your higher ups nicely and explain your situation to them and how you get paid less than others doing a lower down job, you'll have a decent enough foot to stand on. But if you stand there like every other irish person and do nothing about it, dont expect results

Comment: While there may be high unemployment generally in your location, there may still be demand for your specific skill set and experience. Don't write off opportunity without looking first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if jobs are scarce in your area, the best option here is still to start looking for another job. The company is trying to take advantage of the scarcity of jobs in your area and the fact that you're making a request of them to try and save some money by paying you less. The sort of company that does these things is probably not the sort you want to be working for.

And besides that, even if you weren't being asked to take an unjustified pay cut, the cases where people successfully stepped down from a supervisor role into a 'grunt' role, without creating an awkward environment, are exceedingly rare. If you don't enjoy your supervisory role then your best bet is *still* to start looking for a new job.

In the mean time, do whatever is best for your mental health. This might mean stepping back and taking the pay cut so you experience less pressure from the added responsibilities while you're looking for a new position. It might also mean staying on in the supervisor role instead so that your financial situation doesn't add stress while you're looking for a new position.

I'm not suggesting that it will be *easy* to find a new job, but working for an employer who treats their employees like this is never a good idea.

Comment: And there is also the possibility of moving to an area with a better job market.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to stay any longer at the supervisor position and can take the 5% drop, move down. If you can't take the financial hit, stay at your current position.

> I feel intimidated by my manager and I am scared I will be bullied more or let go if I stand up for myself.

In order to negotiate your salary now and in the future, you will need to toughen up and talk with your manager. Tell him how you see things and what value and experience you bring to the company.